# DotNetOpenAuth - How does client authentificate with id and secret?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm just finishing authorization and resource server for OAuth2, using DotNetOpenAuth 4.3.4. For testing, I created test client by implementing OAuth2Client.

Because I'm using DNOA for all the communication and request parsing, I'm not sure if I fully understand what is going on under the hood. But this knowledge is very important when I make documentation.

So, could you please explain to me, how client authentification works in DNOA? I use authorization code as grant_type and when I use my test client to exchange code for access_token, the DNOA somehow validate the client_secret and client_id. I downloaded source code for DNOA, but it not helped.

When I set breakpoint to Oauth2 controller(token method) and parse the request as HttpRequestMessage, i see the request contains "grant_type", "code" and "redirect_uri". But where are client_id and client_secret?

Also, can you tell me where I can find any usable documentation for DNOA? I need to create documentation, which will be valid and usable for all platforms, not just C#, which can use DNOA.

Related question:
*I somewhere read, that we should not create authorization codes for unauthentificated clients, but this is exactly what DNOA does (since I receive authorization code even if secret is wrong). Is it ok?*

**Edit:**

This is the request I'm trying to read. It is token request made by DNOA client. I can not see the client_id and client_secret under other parameters like "code", "redirect_uri" and "grant_type". I tought they have to be together. Maybe I'm missing something important from http requests and responses.

When I let DNOA to HandleTokenRequest(request) to continue, it is successfully authenticate the client application (fails when bad secret is set in DNOA client app config).

[image]

**Edit 2**

```
private readonly WebServerClient Client;    
protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
            {
                var authorization = Client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
                if (authorization != null)
                    return authorization.AccessToken;
                else
                    return null;
            }
```

This is my implementation of QueryAccessToken. It is from some sample. I think I created this at the beginning and did not change it, because it worked.

Going rought DNOA source I found out it is method from OAuth 1. THis can be the problem. But the question is, why it works ok with right client cerdentials and not working with bad ones.

**Final edit**

Looks like DNOA client uses http Basic authorization (client_id and secret are in header). But I need the DNOA server to be able to grab these parameters from POST.

If anyone know how to set DNOA to support client_id and client_secret in POST parameters, it would be awesome!

Thank you

Comment: DNOA is a complicated mess. Don't try and understand what its doing. Just read the OAuth2 spec summaries on the internet.

Comment: I would like to say client develoer "Take OAuth2 specification and develop against it", but I'm afraid DNOA is not implementing everything and not everything is the same. .

Comment: DNOA is not complicated and is not mess. You don't have to explore it all as it does much more than just oauth2. More in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The authorization code grant requires two steps.

The first step is the browser redirecting to the identity provider and displaying the logon ui. The authorization code is returned to the browser by the identity provider and then, from the browser to the client application. This step doesn't involve client secret! This is because the end user can debug this part of the flow and she should not learn the value of the client secret.

Then, when the client application has the onetime authorization code, it concacts the token endpoint directly (server-to-server) to exchange the authorization code for authorization token. This is where client id and client secret are used to verify that only legitimate client applications exchange codes for tokens.

The idea behind this flow is to protect the end user from exposing her password to the client application and also protect the client application from exposing its client secret to the end user.

Also note that the authorization code grant flow is the most complicated one as it involves both username/password (provided by the end user) and clientid/client secret (provided by the client application). There are other flows which allow to get the authorization token in slightly different way, namely:

- resource owner grant which involves sending username/password directly by end user to the token endpoint of the identity provider. This flow is suited for desktop/mobile/native apps where the logon ui can be customized (but it also can raise suspicions and users could proably refuse to use it)
- client credentials flow which involves sending clientid/client secret by the client application to the idntity provider. There is no end user but only the client application authenticating in the identity provider.

More on flows here:

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

As for DNOA, I found it clean and understandable but the docs are lacking. Fortunately, examples are great and although barely documented, you can find almost everything there. Nonetheless, I was able to set up oauth2 identity provider and resource server in three days and support all four oauth2 flows. I am not going to dig deeply into details as this is not what your question is about, however, if you have DNOA specific questions, just ask.

**Edit:**: regarding your `QueryAccessToken` implementation, it seems that you are using the `WebServerClient` internally. In my code I just initialize its properties:

```
WebServerClient client = ...

client.ClientIdentifier = "client_id";
client.ClientCredentialApplicator = 
     ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter( "client_secret" );
```

With these two configured, both `client_id` and `client_secret` are sent to the token service with the `client_secret` passed in POST params.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It is clearer to me now :-) So can you tell me where the client_id and client_secret are? Because when I debug and read the access_token request on token endpoint I'm not able to find client_id or client_secret. I supposed they will be there next to other parameters as I said in my question.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec: Both clientid and clientsecret have to be there, posted from the client application to the token endpoint. DNOA POSTs these, although I believe this is not requires by the oauth2 specs. This could be why you don't see these params as you probably just look at the querystring. If this is not the case, provide more details which particular method you are debugging and I will consult my implementation to verify your concerns.

Comment: I added more explanation of my concerns to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec: I can see that although the token request contains the `code` parameter (which suggests that this request is to exchange the `code` for a token), it lacks both `client_id` and `client_secret`. This is weird and I guess something is wrong at your client application's side. Could you post relevant code snippets from your `WebServerClient` configuration at the client application's side? Specifically, how do you configure the `ClientCredentialApplicator`?

Comment: The client cerdentials has to be validated somehow, since it works when secret is correct and it return "invalid_client" when the secret is incorrect. I'm using default MVC4 OAuth2 implementation for the client app. I do not implement ClientCredentialApplicator. I only created my own TestClient, which inherits from "DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client" and implements some abstract methods. Then I just add this client to the OAuthConfig in global.aspx - "OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new TestClient("TestingClient"));". That is all I did. It works and I don't know why.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec: these all are **most important details** and yet you provide them late, in the middle of the discussion, I thought that you are using `WebServerClient`. Let me check the `OAuth2Client` then. Will be back in few minutes.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec: How is your `QueryAccessToken` method implemented? Seems that this is where the `OAuth2Client` manually creates reqest to the token endpoint.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is written is second row, but I now see I did not said it correctly. I updated my question.

Comment: Thank you. I accualy filling them in constructor. Still I don't see them. If there is one request, I always tought I can send only GET, or POST, but not both combined. I think I'll leave it. It works. I just don't know how.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec: POST extends GET - you still can have nontrivial uri but you also can append non-empty body. Anyway, nice thing is that it works, however, I would also be concerned if I were you. Things don't happen magically :)

Comment: I think I just found out what is it. DNOA uses Basic http authorizetion in Headers (like "Basic mddD3NINMic="). I don't know much about that yet, but what sad is, that it looks like DNOA does not support classic authorization by passing client_id and client_secret by POST parameters.

Comment: It does, I have all four flows implemented and client-id and client-secret are passed to the token endpoint. Note that headers have nothing to do! Headers are used to authenticate consecutive requests to the resource server, the initial request to the token endpoint at the identity server doesn't have to be authenticated with any headers.